# Raster calculator: Insufficient memory available for operation

Tags: qgis, raster

I use QGIS 2.14 (Windows, 64bit) and try to do some raster calculations with EUNIS habitat data, filter for specific habitat types, files are about 3 GB.

RAM: 8 GB (7,85 GB usable)
Virtual RAM: 8043 MB (automatic)

But there is always the following error: Raster calculator: Insufficient memory available for operation.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please **edit** the question to specify how much physical RAM and virtual RAM you have configured on your system, with an indication of how much free RAM was available before you attempted the operation.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use the command line version http://www.gdal.org/gdal_calc.html in the OSGEO4W shell.

Comment: Add also the gdalinfo report about your source data because some raster formats eat more memory than some others.

Comment: @AndreJ: I will try it, but I am not very used to shell.. thanks

Answer (score 3):

For large raster files you can use r.mapcalculator in QGIS Processing Toolbox.

Comment: I am trying this answer, but seems that for that you have to provide all layers you wish to include in your calculation as *individual* layers. Is there an option to use that method with only one raster that has several layers?

Comment: Are you saying about bands of a raster? `one raster that has several layers?`

Comment: I mean that 'r.mapcalculator' receives several single-layered rasters and outputs one single-layered raster (at least that is what I saw on its options). Is there an option to give as input one multi-layered raster and operate with those bands?